# while loop with conditional check between two dates finishes before I expect it to

Tags: python, datetime, csv

I created code to generate a CSV file which contains date and time stamps with 1 hour interval for whole year 2013. Here's my code:

```
from datetime import *
moment=datetime(2013,1,1,0,50)
f = open ("C:\\dates.csv", "w")
while moment<datetime(2014,1,1):
    f.write(str(moment.year)+"."+str(moment.month)+"."+str(moment.day)+";"+str(moment.hour)+":"+str(moment.minute)+"\n")
    moment+=timedelta(minutes=+60)

f.close
```

The problem is that code should generate for the whole year of 2013 but it stops generating after 2013.12.19;01:50. I couldn't find why.What might be the issue?

Comment: `f.close()` is a function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python write to a file returns empty file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048728/python-write-to-a-file-returns-empty-file)

Comment: Changed to "f.close()"  and perfectly works. Just as i suspected a very silly mistake. I'm still confused about why it works until 19.12.2013 but not further. But, thank you very much.

Comment: That depends on the buffer size of stdout, as soon ss it is full data is flushed out.

Answer (score 0):

Change the fourth line to:

```
 while moment < datetime (2014,1,1,0,0):
```

Comment: As it can be seen above the problem was somewhere else, something related with my mistyping. But thank you for input.