# Scrape data to a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, text, web-scraping

I'm wanting to scrape data to a text file instead of a csv.  I feel like I am making this a lot more complicated than it should be and have always used csv's.

As an example lets say I wanted to scrape  `.question-hyperlink` off stackoverflow [homepage](https://stackoverflow.com/)

Txt: (something like)

```
With open('C:/dwadawd.txt', 'a', newline='',
                  encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
            writer = csv.writer(outfile)
            for row in zip(gz_text, ga_href):
                writer.writerow(row)
                print(row)
```

I have also tried the following:

```
#Scrapes from website
    # EXTRACT
    elems = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.question-hyperlink')
    ag_href = []

    for ag in elems:
        ag_href.append(elem.get_attribute("href"))
```

Something like:

```
    f = open('helloworld.txt', 'a')
    w.write(str(ag_href))
    f.write(' ')
```

The output just appears to be blank.

I have tried different methods but the results are the same.  Any help?

Comment: please try to give a more in depth example, create a simple, example html file and try your code against that, show what code your using, what output you would expect and what your actually getting

Comment: Try opening CMD and printing in python and piping to a file? `python the_script.py > /dir/folder/data.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048728/python-write-to-a-file-returns-empty-file) question.

You have to flush the file after each `write` function call:

```
f.flush()
```

To avoid this, you can open the file using `with`, this ensures the file is closed:

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('some text')
```

Comment: I'll try that now and I'm going to read all the high voted python text file questions :)

Comment: Got it working.  But all the text is on one line so not very readable.

Comment: @Tmaker For that you need to write a newline to the file `f.write('\n')`. An easier way is to just append `\n` to each string like `+ '\n'`.

Comment: That works thanks.  Though the data is not being scraped correctly.  https://pastebin.com/1HKnWNBt .  The output is []

Comment: @Tmaker Can you post the full script? I can't analyze the problem without knowing where the data is being scraped from.

Comment: We're not dealing with strings here but scraped text. http://textuploader.com/dquau . Hmm

Comment: @Tmaker I think a better way is to use hooks i.e. search by class name. You could first find the table with `class="result"` and then search for the `a` tag, like this:
`li = soup.find("table", { "class" : "result" })
a_tag = li.find("a")["href"]`

Comment: Is that beautiful soup?        li = soup.find("table", {"class": "result"})
        a_tag = li.find("a")["href"] gives unresolved reference for         from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Comment: @Tmaker You might need to use it like `BeautifulSoup.find(...)`. It depends on how you import the package.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm getting AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'find_all'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160249/discussion-between-adeel-ahmad-and-tmaker).

Comment: Okay, yeap I see the issue.  It comes up blank even with a csv.  Not sure why, but this is likely a windows specific issue.