# Writing to file during infinite while

Tags: python, file, while-loop, ping

I need to write in a txt file during a infinite while. But it's not writing and if I don't use infinite while it's works.
What do I have to change ? 
My goal is to ping different ip infinite time and when the ping fails, it's written in the file with the time and date

I've tried the code without the `while True` and it works.
I think the code need to be stop to write but can we do without stop ?

```
import os
import datetime

fichier = open("log.txt", "a")
date = datetime.datetime.now()

hostnames = [
    '192.168.1.1',
    '192.168.1.2',
    '192.168.1.3',
]
while True :
    for hostname in hostnames:
        ping = os.system(" Ping " + str(hostname))
        if ping == 1:
            print("DOWN")
            fichier.write(str(date) + "    " + str(hostname) + '\n' + '\n')
        else:
            print("UP")
```

I expect the output when it's failed with a stamp Date/Time and the IP Address

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048728/python-write-to-a-file-returns-empty-file, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18984092/python-2-7-write-to-file-instantly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python write to a file returns empty file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048728/python-write-to-a-file-returns-empty-file)

Comment: you never close the file?

Comment: @kvorobiev not really. Cause is not about flushing the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up all the answers in one:

```
try:
 with open('log.txt', 'a') as fichier:
   while True:
       for hostname in hostnames:
           ping = os.system(" Ping " + str(hostname))
           if ping == 1:
           print("DOWN")
           fichier.flush()
           fichier.write(str(date) + "    " + str(hostname) + '\n' + '\n')
       else:
           print("UP")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
     print("Done!")
```

Comment: This is not likely to behave any differently to the OP's current code. You are not flushing to the file.

Comment: That's better. Now we open and close file only once. Thanks for improving!

Comment: @FUNNYDMAN but it doesn't flush the buffered writes

Comment: Thank's for the missing flush