# Incorrect size of file in Python

Tags: python

Consider:

```
import os

def create_python_script(filename):
    comments = "# Start of a new Python Program"
    #filesize = 0
    with open(filename, 'w') as new_file:
        new_file.write(comments)
        cwd = os.getcwd()
        fpath = os.path.abspath(filename)
        filesize = os.path.getsize(fpath)
    return(filesize)

print(create_python_script('newprogram.py'))
```

I am getting the result as zero, but it should get "31".

Comment: Text files have a default buffer in the order of 4kiB. Since your text is smaller, it is not flushed until the file is closed. Check the file size *outside* of the with context.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python write to a file returns empty file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048728/python-write-to-a-file-returns-empty-file)

Answer (score 3):

You didn't close your file before trying to get its size, as you do it inside the `with` block. Take it outside:

```
import os

def create_python_script(filename):
    comments = "# Start of a new Python Program"
    #filesize = 0
    with open(filename, 'w') as new_file:
        new_file.write(comments)
        cwd=os.getcwd()
        fpath = os.path.abspath(filename)
        print(fpath)

    filesize=os.path.getsize(fpath)
    return(filesize)

print(create_python_script('newprogram.py'))
# 31
```

Answer (score 0):

First opening the file with write permissions to add the text in the file. Then opening the file with read permissions to get the size of the file.

```
import os

def create_python_script(filename):
    comments = "# Start of a new Python program"
    with open(filename, 'w') as pd:
        pd.write(comments)

    with  open(filename, "r"):
        filesize = os.path.getsize(filename)
        print(filesize)
    return filesize

print(create_python_script("program.py"))
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. You help is appreciated, but please provide explanations for answer & code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/late-answers/26221868)

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

def create_python_script(filename):
  comments = "# Start of a new Python program"
  with open(filename, 'w') as file:
    file.write(comments)
    file.close()
    filepath = os.path.abspath(filename)
    filesize = os.path.getsize(filepath)
  return(filesize)

print(create_python_script("program.py"))

#this will give you correct result
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

This one is working perfectly too!

```
    def create_python_script(filename):
      import os
      comments = "# Start of a new Python program"
      with open(filename,'w')as file:
         file.write(comments)
      filesize = os.path.getsize(filename)
      return(filesize)
    print(create_python_script("program.py"))
```