# Unable to write chromedriver page_source to file

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to write a chromedriver `page_source` into a file. That fails: I see an empty file, with no error message.

The issue is not the file creation -- my question is *not* addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048728/python-write-to-a-file-returns-empty-file). The file is properly being opened with `with open .. as f` and closed by `f.close`. When replacing the driver page_source by a dummy string 'hello', the file will also write just fine.

The following code runs without error message, also creates the file, but leaves it empty at 0 KB:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'chromedriver.exe', options=options)
driver.get(url)

with open('myFile.html', "w") as f:
    f.write(driver.page_source)
    f.close()
```

The driver runs fine, also the value of driver.page_source seems to be ok. If I run `print(driver.page_source)`, it shows some meaningful HTML code:

```
print(driver.page_source)
>>> <html lang="de" style="" class="js flexbox ...
```

The following code also runs without errors, and produces the expected result: A file containing the string 'hello':

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'chromedriver.exe', options=options)
driver.get(url)

with open('myFile.html', "w") as f:
    f.write('hello')
    f.close()
```

Why?

What is happening inside `write`, combined with the actual value of `driver.page_source`, that will prevent the file from writing?

Comment: What URL are you calling in get()?

Answer (score 0):

Have you noticed the exception thrown on attempt to write the file? Was it `UnicodeEncodeError`? If so you need to add desired encoding:

`with open('myFile.html', "w", encoding='utf-8') as f:`

Also, when you use `with` clause, you don't need adding `f.close()`